# How to configure Symfony 4 with Nginx + PHP-FPM while CHROOT

Tags: php, symfony, nginx, chroot

My Symfony site runs fine when Not Chroot with PHP-FPM.
However, when I enable chroot my site breaks with a 500 error and no nginx logs.

The site does initially run but breaks on line 25:

```
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
```

I have changed my nginx conf file accordingly to properly execute the site in the chroot environment. Mainly, just replacing `$realpath_root` with `/public`.  The same chroot setup works fine for other sites like WordPress, but it seems Symfony does not.

Here is my php-fpm pool file:

```
[website.com]
prefix = /srv/web/$pool
user = web
group = web
listen = /run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 5
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 3
chroot = $prefix
chdir = /
php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 256M
php_admin_value[upload_max_filesize] = 256M
php_admin_value[post_max_size] = 256M
php_admin_value[cgi.fix_pathinfo]=0
php_admin_value[max_execution_time] = 300
php_admin_value[max_input_vars] = 5000
```

Here is my Nginx server block website.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name website.com www.website.com;

    root /srv/web/website.com/public;

    access_log    /var/log/nginx/website.com.access.log;
    error_log     /var/log/nginx/website.com.error.log;

    index index.php index.html;

    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to index.php
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /public$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT /public;
        internal;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 404;
    }
}
```

Everything works if remove chroot by changing:

```
chroot = $prefix
chdir = /
```

to

```
;chroot = $prefix
;chdir = /
```

and

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /public$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT /public;
```

to

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
```

I am assuming that Symfony may not work in this environment or needs some sort of configuration to work.  Again, there are no error logs reported in  /var/log/nginx/website.com.error.log so it makes it very difficult to understand what the issue is.

Comment: Have you check [this documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html#nginx) ?

Comment: @Mcsky Yes, I have, thanks, but it only refers to non-chroot.  I haven't been able to find any documentation on Symfony Nginx PHP-FPM Chroot, but if you find some then please post.  Thanks